# Добавить в строку пробелы каждые 3 символа

Tags: double, android, java, строки

```
Double tCountDouble = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(recieveTCount));
Double towPrDouble = Double.parseDouble(towPr);
Double sumTaskDouble = towPrDouble * tCountDouble;
String sumTask = String.valueOf(sumTaskDouble);
```

А потом уже sumTask идет в TextView.

```
tv.setText(sumTask);
```

Но так как sumTask - результат умножения, то итог выходит `1234.0` или `1234.98`. Нужно целую часть разбить.

Нужно получить из результата 7845.0 следующий - 7 845.0

Comment: String.format Вам в помощь

Comment: Да, я знаю о галочках.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setGroupingUsed(true);
df.setGroupingSize(3);

DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = getDecimalFormatSymbols();
decimalFormatSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
decimalFormatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');

df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);
String sample = df.format(1023.3443d)
```

Comment: А можно небольшое пояснение к коду ?

Comment: @Andreich, разделение происходит корректно, но выводятся нули.
вывел в лог. получил следующее:
0 000 000.0
а строка была: 2527968.0

Comment: @web_alex я не понимаю, в чем ваша проблема.   
http://take.ms/fUiZ2  
Можете привести пример вашего использования?

Comment: @Andreich, код находится в вопросе. Далее нужно разбить sumTask, если оно 3-х-значное.
Ваш код выводил все время нули. То есть, к примеру, число 123900.0 он представил как 000 000.0. Разбито правильно, но цифры не те. А потом вовсе отказался выводить нули. Посыпались какие-то случайные числа правильного порядка.

Comment: @web_alex мне кажется, вы использовали как-то не так.

Comment: @Andreich, да, Вы правы. Я действительно не так использовал Ваш код. 
Нужно было не строку подставлять, а Double значение, тогда все корректно работает. И работает лучше, чем я вообще хотел сделать.


@ЮрийСПб, Вы уж простите, что снял "галочку" с Вашего ответа. Ваш код тоже хорош! По нему можно учиться логике работы в подобных вопросах. Плюс я Вам поставлю! А галочку получил @Andreich. Его код на много меньше.

Comment: @web_alex, никаких претензий) Ответ @Andreich, конечно, вернее.

Answer (score 3):

А я вот такой велосипед соорудил:

```
String sumTask = "7123261836287368246192391273845.0";
    //сначала ставим первый пробел перед точкой.
    //находим индекс точки в строке
    int pointPosition = sumTask.indexOf(".");
    //вставим первый пробел, разделив строку на две части (до и после точки) и склеив обратно.
    sumTask = sumTask.substring(0, pointPosition - 3) + " " + sumTask.substring(pointPosition - 3);
    //теперь от пробела к началу строки ставим остальные пробелы
    for (int i = 0; i < pointPosition / 3; i++)
    {
        //находим последний вставленный пробел
        int lastSpacePosition = sumTask.indexOf(" ");
        //проверяем, не выйдем ли мы за пределы строки, вставляя новый. Если да - завершаем цикл.
        if((lastSpacePosition - 3)>0)
        {
            sumTask = sumTask.substring(0, lastSpacePosition - 3) + " " + sumTask.substring(lastSpacePosition - 3);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sumTask);
```

Выведет: 7 123 261 836 287 368 246 192 391 273 845.0

Ответ [@Andreich](/users/5345/andreich), конечно, элегантнее, но я отвечать начал ещё до публикации его ответа)